# emacs: M-x shell and color codes (^[[0G[1])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, emacs, ansi-escape

(Using latest OS X and latest emacs available on homebrew)
Inside emacs when I do

```
M-x shell
```

And then launch a REPL console with

```
rails console
```

I get

```
bash-3.2$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0)
^[[0G[1] pry(main)>
```

Instead of nice colors, I see ^[[0G[1]
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In emacs,

```
M-x shell
```

gives you a "dumb" shell which does not interpret escape codes.  You could do

```
M-x term
```

but should be aware that the escape sequence used by rails is not supported by that, either.  It is a control sequence (with an incorrect parameter, by the way) which would move the cursor to the first column — on some terminals, such as xterm.

You'd typically see behavior like that from a hard-coded application, and if you're patient, a bug report to its developer might be productive.

Further reading:

- [EmacsWiki: Ansi Term](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTerm)
- [What is the difference between shell, eshell, and term in Emacs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104325/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-eshell-and-term-in-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an older version of pry installed, do

```
bash$ DISABLE_PRY_RAILS=1 rails console
```

this worked for me